# Check LDAP store for changes in attributes

Tags: c#, ldap

Is it possible to check if a users atrributes have changed when you query an LDAP. What I want to do is, everytime i run my program i want it to search the ldap and if two attribiutes change, IE from 3 to 0, and Active to Withdrawn, then write those users to a file.

Is this possible?

Comment: Modern professional-quality directory servers support the concept of a "persistent search". The connection remains open and returns entries and values matching the filter when they change in real-time. It may be necessary to advise your directory server administrator that you wish to use persistent search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the operational attribute `modifyTimestamp`. That tells you when *anything* changed in the entry. So you could formulate a search filter something like `(&(modifyTimestamp > xxxx)(|(IE=0)(yyy=Withdrawn))))`, and remember the last time you ran the search for the next value of `xxxx`.